# Ratio Test for Convergence on a series: $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^3+1}{\sqrt[3]{n^{10} + n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Is the ratio test for convergence applicable to the below series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^3+1}{\sqrt[3]{n^{10} + n}}$$

I already know that the series diverge. I want to confirm if the ratio test is applicable or not?

Comment: what is your answer?

Comment: I dont know the answer. The question comes from a MCA question with 10 options, and I have to choose the ones that fail ratio test or root test for convergence

Comment: The ratio test is inconclusive if the ratio goes to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's compute the ratio

$${a_{n+1}\over a_n}={(n+1)^3+1\over n^3+1}\cdot {\sqrt[3]{(n+1)^{10}+n+1}\over \sqrt[3]{n^{10}+n}}\sim{n^{1\over 3}\over(n+1)^{1\over3}}\to 1$$

We cannot conclude with the ratio test

Answer (score 1):

If the limit of the ratio $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = 1$$ Then the Ratio Test is **Inconclusive**. The test does not tell you anything about the series. The series may diverge or converge conditionally or absolutely.

**As such, it would not be correct to say that the series *fails* the ratio test.** It fails when the above limit is *strictly greater* than $1$.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**: Compare your series with $\displaystyle \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^{\frac{1}{3}}}$, which diverges.

Comment: I understand that the series diverge. The question is ratio test applicable here?

Comment: The ratio test is not useful here since its $1$.

Answer (score 0):

What about of the integral test?

We have $$\frac{n^3+1}{\sqrt[3]{n^{10}+n}}> \frac{n^3+1}{\sqrt[3]{n^{10}+n^{10}}}= \frac{n^3+1}{2n^{10/3}}$$
Now, the integral
$$\int_1^{\infty}\frac{x^3+1}{2x^{10/3}}dx$$
diverges. Then, the given series diverges too.